custom formatter for the y-axis labels causing the labels to be partially hidden
I'm trying to configure my Highcharts to display a "$" character prior to their default format. it works fine however the yAxis label is partially hidden because highchart doesn't automatically resize the labels width
Note: I'm using Highchart 9.3.3
yAxis:{
  labels: {
    formatter: {
      this.axis.defaultLabelFormatter.call(this)
    }
  }
}



If you want to add a "$" before the yAxis labels I suggest using yAxis.labels.format option.
API references: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.labels.format
Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3mp5ghrc/
yAxis: {
labels: {
  format: '${text}'
},

},

You can try to use yAxis.offset to align label. This can be useful
yAxis: {
  offset: 30,
  labels: { 
    align: 'left',
  }
}

or remove chart.margin if you are using it
